# How to randomly get a value from a table

Tags: lua

So i'm trying to pick a random value from a table.
Like math.random(1, 3) but with table values.

```
t = {}

local tests = {1111, 2222, 3333}

for i = 1, #tests do
    table.insert(t, tests[i])
end
```

I tried this

```
t[math.random(1, #t)]
```

But i keep getting ALWAYS the last value[row] which would be "3333"

How is supposed to be to get randomly 1 value from the table?

Comment: why is it that no one is reading the Lua manual?

Comment: @Piglet - Lua manual says NOTHING about necessity of initializing pseudo-random generator used by Lua.  Some systems do not require such initialization.  For example, in Oracle one can simply write `dbms_random.value` without all that headache about not forgetting to take current time and feed it as a PRNG seed.  Yes, Oracle has `dbms_random.seed` procedure but you can live happily without knowing it exists.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That's not quite correct. The Lua manual says that same seeds result in same numbers and that the underlying random generator is the one provided by C (which uses the default seed 1 as stated in the C reference). It might not be the nicest way to tell your user, but that information is definitely there. Besides any resource that websearch  yields for "lua random" explains that as well. Not to mention the respective chapter in Programming in Lua...

Comment: @Piglet - The paragraph **math.random ([m [, n]])** says nothing about "same seeds result in same numbers".  Re-read it.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I know. It's 1 line below, in the only other paragraph related to random numbers... sorry if that's too much to ask for. You said manual, you did not refer to any specific paragraph. But I'm not here to argue... Good day